# NSUserDefaults and NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone

When saving an array in the userdefaults using the `setObject` method, is it then ok to just `setObject:myMutableArray` or do I need to wrap it in
`[NSArray arrayWithArray:myMutableArray];` ? The first one should work right? Since it is a subclass of NSArray, and it wont affect other things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a problem with what you're trying to do, however bear in mind that when you get an object back from user defaults you always get it immutable.

A nice approach can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277755/change-objects-in-nsuserdefaults-without-creating-and-re-setting-copies) to make it easy to work it.